# c++ attempting to reference deleted function

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have been playing around with `std::unique_ptr` and the `std::for_each` algorithm to learn them and I then received this error "attempting to reference a deleted function" when I am attempting to move some variables from one container (`std::map`) to another.

This code is currently executed in a member function. `Foo` is just a generic class.

```
std::for_each(m_list1.begin(), m_list1.end(),
              [&](std::pair<std::size_t,std::unique_ptr<Foo>> data_pair)
              {
                m_list2[data_pair.first] = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(std::move(data_pair.second));
              });
m_list1.clear();
```

I tried various things but the problems still persists. I then tried using range-based for instead and suddenly it works.

```
for (auto& data_pair : m_list1)
{
    m_list2[data_pair.first] = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(std::move(data_pair.second));
}
m_list1.clear();
```

What I want to know is why the second code executed with no problem, while the first code produced the error.

If you need more specific information, Just ask. If there's bad practice in my coding style, please advice on how to make it better.

Comment: Try changing your lambda to `[&](std::pair<std::size_t,std::unique_ptr<Foo>>& data_pair)`. If you take the `data_pair` by value, `for_each` will attempt to make a copy of the `unique_ptr` when it calls the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your `for_each` code. First, `map::value_type` is `pair<const Key, Value>`. Second, your lambda expression is taking the argument by value, which means it attempts to copy the `unique_ptr`, hence the error. To fix it, take the argument by reference.

```
[&](std::pair<const std::size_t, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>& data_pair)
//            ^^^^^                                  ^^^
{
  m_list2[data_pair.first] = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(std::move(data_pair.second));
}
```

---

A better option is to not mention those types explicitly, instead use `decltype`

```
[&](decltype(m_list1)::value_type& data_pair)
{
  m_list2[data_pair.first] = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(std::move(data_pair.second));
}
```

---

Now, your range-based `for` worked because you were binding the elements of the `map` to a reference by using `for(auto& data_pair : m_list1)`. You'd have run into the same error as before if you'd instead used `for(auto data_pair : m_list1)` because that'd have attempted to make a copy of the elements.